# First step to take learning matrices in WEBGL

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

After drawing a simple triangle in webgl, I've decided to start to learn how to do transformations. So basically I'm thinking that the simplest thing I can do is to write an identity matrix and multiply it for the vertex positions.

So I've added to the code the identity matrix as

```
var identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0,
                      0,1,0,0,
                      0,0,1,0,
                      0,0,0,1];
```

Then I've added to the shader the mat4 variable as

```
'uniform mat4 id_matrix;'
```

And multiplied it for the position (so I'm expecting no changes in the transformations at all, since I multiply everything by 1)

```
gl_Position = id_matrix * vec4 (a_position,1);
```

Finally I retrieve the location of the matrix in the shader and fill it with my data

```
var shaderIdentityMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "id_matrix");
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderIdentityMatrix,false,new Float32Array(identityMatrix));
```

But after those changes, nothing appears on screen. Am I doing wrong assumptions?

Here's the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<canvas id = "can" width="400" height="400">

</canvas>


<script>
var webgl_canvas = document.getElementById('can');
var gl = webgl_canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
var triangles = [-0.8,-0.8,0,0.8,-0.8,0,0,0.8,0];
var identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0,
                      0,1,0,0,
                      0,0,1,0,
                      0,0,0,1];    
var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(triangles), gl.STATIC_DRAW); 

vertexBuffer.itemSize = 3;
vertexBuffer.numItems = 3;





var vertexShader_source = 'attribute vec3 a_position;' + 'uniform mat4 id_matrix;' + 'void main() { gl_Position = id_matrix * vec4 (a_position,1); }';
var fragmentShader_source = 'precision mediump float;' + 'void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.9,0,0.1,1); }';









//Compile shaders
var buildShader = function (shaderSource, typeOfShader) {
var shader = gl.createShader(typeOfShader);
gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
gl.compileShader(shader);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert (gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
}
return shader;
}

var compiledVertexShader = buildShader (vertexShader_source, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
var compiledFragmentShader = buildShader (fragmentShader_source, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

//setup GLSL program
program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program,compiledVertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program,compiledFragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);


//Draw
var shaderIdentityMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "id_matrix");
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderIdentityMatrix,false,new Float32Array(identityMatrix));
var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_position");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.useProgram(program);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.drawArrays (gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertexBuffer.numItems);
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 gl.uniformMatrix4fv
```

always operates on the currently used shader program. Since there is no shader program activated when you call this function, nothing is set. Calling

```
 gl.useProgram(program);
```

directly before the uniformMatrix4fv statement should fix your problem.

Hint: Always check the javascript error console. At least for me (Chrome) it tells me that

```
 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv: location is not from current program
```

which is a good indicator for where to search for the problem.

Comment: Strange because getAttribLocation worked even before program was called.

Comment: Thats correct. But when you look at the functions you will notice that you have to enter the program-id in getAttribLocation but not in uniformMatrix4fv. :)